# Capturing image generated dynamically when scraping a page

Tags: php, ruby, web-scraping

I'm trying to capture some images from an old database.

When writing scrapers, I use ruby (but am comfortable with php as well) to directly open() a website and read its contents. I sometimes also use the script to call the appropriate `curl ...` command.

However, the database I'm scraping some pieces out of returns a page and then embeds the target image with an image name using a series of random numbers I assume by the server side script. For example:

`<img ... show_image.jsp?343523.jpg`

However, I cannot call this show_image script directly (denied), it only works when embedded in the website as a whole.

Can I use curl, or within ruby or php do something download the entire page, for example, `1929.2.14.aspx` in such a way that it includes the embedded image generated by `show_image.jsp?343523.jpg`?

If I simply curl the aspx file directly, I naturally just get the html - how might one save both the html and embedded image via scripting in the manner that a browser-based "web archive" feature works manually?

Any tips, links to tutorials, etc. appreciated...

Comment: I suspect you can call the script (show_image.jsp?343523.jpg) directly, you may just need to specify the site URL as the referrer.  This is in effect what happens when your browser loads the whole page.

Comment: This might work for you... http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: If you can access it in the browser, then it is accessible. There's no way the end script would know. Maybe you need to spoof the referrer as @drew010 pointed out, or maybe you need to set the user agent, a cookie, or perhaps some other request header. But it's definitely scriptable.

Comment: The referer idea is a great one but doesn't quite work. I tried with `curl --referer` but the result is the same as when I load the image directly in the browser. I am thinking that something is going on behind the scenes when you load the page as a whole. In fact, the id for the image changes every time you reload the page.

Comment: It's possible there's some JavaScript involved making the browser send POST request with some validation fields to the show_image script. Would you mind providing the site's URL?

Comment: Would it possible to post the link to the page directly so we can test some solutions ourselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably be using mechanize to scrape websites in ruby. When you do it will set cookies and referer for you so getting the image will be as easy as:

```
agent.get(image_url).save_as 'local_filename.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the script (show_image.jsp - for example) is doing a simple referrer check, you may be able to work around it by writing your PHP (or Ruby) scraper in such a way so as to set the referrer before making the GET:

```
curl --referer http://www.example.com http://www.example.com/show_image.jsp?bar.jpg
```

Comment: The referer idea is a good one but doesn't work. The id number of the image also changes with each reload-I suspect it gets dynamically generated with the aspx page itself and perhaps only loads once? I thus some how need to call the aspx page and grab the image together with it...but thanks for the try!